# I'm trying to run javascript with JSContext evaluateScript on a URL

Tags: javascript, swift

I'm trying to use `evaluateScript` on a URL. In the documentation it shows:

```
func evaluateScript(_ script: String!, withSourceURL sourceURL: URL!) -> JSValue!
```

```
func initializeJS() {
    self.jsContext = JSContext()

    // Specify the path to the jssource.js file.
    if let jsSourcePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Rejistration", ofType: "js") {
        do {
            // Load its contents to a String variable.
            let jsSourceContents = try String(contentsOfFile: jsSourcePath)

            // Add the Javascript code that currently exists in the jsSourceContents to the Javascript Runtime through the jsContext object.
            let newURL = URL(string: "https://google.com/")
            self.jsContext.evaluateScript(jsSourceContents, newURL )

            if let variableHelloWorld = self.jsContext.objectForKeyedSubscript("helloWorld") {
                print(variableHelloWorld.toString())
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
```

Error on the line:

```
self.jsContext.evaluateScript(jsSourceContents, newURL )
```

Error says:

> Cannot invoke 'evaluateScript' with an argument list of type '(String, URL?)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget the `withSourceURL:` argument label.

```
self.jsContext.evaluateScript(jsSourceContents, withSourceURL: newURL)
```

You also need a non-optional URL. So either force-unwrap `newURL` if you know it can't fail or safely unwrap it before trying to use it.

Comment: tried dosent give me errors anymore
would you happen to know why it dosent run the script on the url ?

Comment: That's a completely different issue deserving its own separate question. This answer addresses the issue you posted in this original question.